# Some keys ( 'w' , 'g', 'f' , 'y', 'h', etc) are not working properly on Ubuntu 22.04 whereas working well on windows

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, lg

While typing some keys like <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd>, etc are not working for the first key press. It works after multiple key presses.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on LG Gram.
Previously it used to work fine, looks like after some updates it started behaving this way.
It works fine on windows btw.

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard

    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard bouncekeys-beep-reject false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard bouncekeys-delay 300
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard bouncekeys-enable false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard disable-timeout 200
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard enable false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard feature-state-change-beep false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-accel-time 300
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-init-delay 300
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-max-speed 10
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-beep-accept false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-beep-press false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-beep-reject false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-delay 300
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-enable false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-enable false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-modifier-beep false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-two-key-off false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard timeout-enable false
    org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard togglekeys-enable false
```